# Environment based auth provider in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to switch the auth provider based on the current environment in Symfony 3.4? An example would be to use LDAP (`http_basic_ldap`) while in production and `http_basic` while in dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try this, but it should be simple.

Remove the `security.yml` import from `config.yml`.

Create `security_prod.yml` and `security_dev.yml` and import them in `config_prod.yml` and `config_dev.yml`.

You could also leave the `security.yml` imported, and put common stuff, like role hierarchy in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a copy of security.yaml file in config/packages/dev, /prod, and /test and remove the original file.

This is the way to do it in symfony 4